# How to get actionbar home button to clear nav stack?

Tags: android

In my app, I have called the following to enable the home button on my actionbar:

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

and clicking the app icon on my actionbar seems to start a new instance of my main activity. I was expecting my entire activity stack to be cleared though instead (similar to starting the main activity with the clear_top flag). Instead it looks like a new instance of my main activity is just put on top of the stack.

Is this the default behavior, or do we need to do something extra to get the home button to clear the nav stack for us?

I'm not using actionbarsherlock.

Thanks

----- Edit ------

This is what my manifest looks like:

```
<activity 
  android:name="com.me.ActivityHorse"
  android:parentActivityName="com.me.ActivityMain" />
```

Comment: Have you specified in the `AndroidManifest` that which activity is the appropriate parent for each activity?

Comment: Just added it but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: try adding `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in your parent activity and please share xml of both parent and child activities.

Comment: It is working absolutely for me. I am not sure that you are following http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: Ah ok I was cobbling this together from various other posts, the doc you linked to of course makes it work. Can you add that as an answer so I can give you credit, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you dont want to create a new instance of an activity you have [Manage Android Tasks](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManagingTasks) manually.
2. If you want to provide [Up Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) in your app you have specific parent-ancestor relationship in the AndroidManifest.xml
3. You only have to create a new back stack only if your activity is starting from a different app.
4. [Follow Android Official Guide for implementing navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html)

***Always first take a look on official Android docs before learning something new about 
Android before following any unofficial blog.***

Comment: though android-docs are pretty hard to read if you try to understand a new topic